# will the maximum number of rows decrease after records are deleted from a table as the row id keeps incrementing

Tags: sqlite

This might be a beginners question, but when testing my sqlite data base, I found that when I delete a row, the row id keeps incrementing when I insert a new row and doesn't reuse for instance the row id of a deleted row. So, what will happen if the row id runs out to it's maximum value, while there are less rows in the table?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: I don't think that will happen before I die, but theoretically I could run out and have just one row in the table :-). Ok, so I don't need to be worried, thanks..

Answer (score 3):

This is [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> If the table has previously held a row with the largest possible ROWID, then new INSERTs are not allowed and any attempt to insert a new row will fail with an SQLITE_FULL error.

If you omit the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword, IDs will still autoincrement, but can be reused if you delete the last row or if the values overflow:

> If the largest ROWID is equal to the largest possible integer (9223372036854775807) then the database engine starts picking positive candidate ROWIDs at random until it finds one that is not previously used.

Answer (score 0):

When you add row number as auto increment you have to check largest value. If data rows go to that limit you have to use bigger data type. But usually integer doesn't cross because a database designer must keep eye on [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

If data rows give so big. You are really stuck with the queries. It will take huge time. `SQLite` is mainly useful for low end device. They are not so capable of handling big data.